# Can not run few methods sequentially when Spring Boot starts

Tags: spring, spring-boot, netty, startup, autostart

I have to run a few methods when Application starts, like the following:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    private final MonitoringService monitoringService;
    private final QrReaderServer qrReaderServer;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        monitoringService.launchMonitoring();
        qrReaderServer.launchServer();
    }
```

However, only the first one is executed! And the application is started:

```
... Started Application in 5.21 seconds (JVM running for 6.336)
... START_MONITORING for folder: D:\results
```

The second one is always skipped!

If change the call order - the only the second one will be executed.

Could not find any solution for launching both at the beginning - tried `@PostConstruct`, `ApplicationRunner`, `@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)`...

Looks like they are blocking each other somehow. Despite the fact that ***both have void type***.

Monitoring launch implementation:

```
@Override
public void launchMonitoring() {
    log.info("START_MONITORING for folder: {}", monitoringProperties.getFolder());
    try {
        WatchKey key;
        while ((key = watchService.take()) != null) {
            for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {

                WatchEvent.Kind<?> kind = event.kind();

                if (kind == ENTRY_CREATE) {
                    log.info("FILE_CREATED: {}", event.context());

                    // some delay for fully file upload
                    Thread.sleep(monitoringProperties.getFrequency());

                    String fullFileName = getFileName(event);
                    String fileName = FilenameUtils.removeExtension(fullFileName);

                    processResource(fullFileName, fileName);
                }
            }
            key.reset();
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        log.error("interrupted exception for monitoring service", e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("io exception while processing file", e);
    } 
}
```

QR Reader start (launch TCP server with Netty configuration):

```
@Override
public void launchServer() {
    try {
        ChannelFuture serverChannelFuture = serverBootstrap.bind(hostAddress).sync();
        log.info("Server is STARTED : port {}", hostAddress.getPort());

        serverChannel = serverChannelFuture.channel().closeFuture().sync().channel();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    } finally {
        shutdownQuietly();
    }
}
```

***How to solve this issue?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start `launchMonitoring()` asynchronously.

The easiest way to do this is to enable Async by adding `@EnableAsync` on your Application
and then annotate `launchMonitoring()` with `@Async`

Not sure if `launchServer()` should also be started asynchronously.

*EDIT: completed Answer*

`No task executor bean found for async processing: no bean of type TaskExecutor and no bean named 'taskExecutor' either`

By default Spring will create a `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor`, but you can provide your taskExecutor

Example:

```java
 @EnableAsync
 @Configuration
 public class AsyncConfig implements AsyncConfigurer {

     @Override
     public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
         ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
         executor.set... // your custom configs
         executor.initialize();
         return executor;
     }

    ...
 }
```

Comment: make only `launchMonitoring()` - and it works like charming

Comment: Discovered some strange snipped at log `No task executor bean found for async processing: no bean of type TaskExecutor and no bean named 'taskExecutor' either`. Do I need to add some task executor? Everything is working fine for now.

Comment: @nazar_art complete my answer

Comment: I set thread name for `AsyncConfig` - `carpark-ex-1` + 4 initial threads. And see that it is always executed with only be 1 thread `carpark-ex-1`. Do I need to make this bean with prototype scope for execution with multiple threads?

Comment: why should you want to execute `launchMonitoring()` with multiple threads?

Comment: Why otherwise, have to set something like `executor.setMaxPoolSize()` for `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`.